# JavaFX macOs Mojave

Tags: javafx

Bom dia,

Estou com dificuldades no JavaFX. 
Instalei o E(fx)clipse versão 3.4.1

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Hello World!");
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

A aplicação corre sem erros. No entanto a janela não aparece. Apenas aparece o icone na dock.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tente rodar com Java 8. Salvo engano o e(fx)clipse ainda não é compatível com java 9+

Answer (score 0):

Problema resolvido. 
Mesmo usando java 11. Bastou retirar um check logo abaixo dos argumentos.

Conforme a imagem em anexo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]